# dart/flutter; how to insert data into database starting from a SQL file

Tags: sql, database, flutter, dart

I have the following local **surveys.sql** file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "surveys" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "title" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    "description" varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    "questions" varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

INSERT INTO "surveys" (id, title, description, questions)
VALUES
(1, 'title2','desc2','questions2'),
(2, 'title2','desc2','questions2'),
(3, 'title3','desc3','questions3');
```

In order to initialize this database, I have the following class:

```
class DatabaseService {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await _initialize();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<String> get fullPath async {
    const name = "surveys.sql";
    final path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return join(path, name);
  }

  Future<Database> _initialize() async {
    final path = await fullPath;
    var database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: create,
      singleInstance: true,
    );
    return database;
  }

  Future<void> create(Database database, int version) async =>
      await TodoDB().createTable(database);

}
```

where the create method is used in another class that has this code:

```
  final String surveys = 'resources/surveys.sql';
  
  Future<void> createTable(Database database) async {
    await database.execute(surveys);
    await database.rawInsert(surveys);
  }
```

Everything compiles, the database is created (for what I can tell), but the data is not there (I get an empty list of surveys). I haven't been able to find anywhere how to populate a database from local file.

I'm still new to databases, flutter and dart, so I'm sorry in advance if the answer is obvious! I'm a student and still learning!